# Kotlin Web App | link css file

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm new in Kotlin and Java and started with this example: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/httpservlets.html

I used Gradle to build the app and I got it working. In the next step I tried to link a CSS file but I get always 404 errors. I created the css file here: src/main/resources/css/style.css

Gradle copied the file to this location: build/resources/main/css/style.css and I used this path to link it in the source code.

```
package org.jetbrains.kotlin.demo

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

@WebServlet(name = "Hello", value = "/hello")
class HomeController : HttpServlet() {
    override fun doGet(req: HttpServletRequest, res: HttpServletResponse) {
        res.writer.write(myView("nice headline"))
    }

    fun myView(headline: String ): String  {
        var content = """<!DOCTYPE html><html>
            |<head>
            |<link href="./build/resources/main/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
            |</head>
            |<body><h1>$headline</h1></body>
            |</html>""".trimMargin()
        return content
    }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong here? 
THX!

Comment: I found another solution to serve the css. I created a `webapp` directory in `/src/main/`. My css is located here: `/src/main/webapp/css/style.css` To link it in the header I use http://localhost:xxxx/first-project/css/style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serve your CSS file, you cannot just have a relative link to the filesystem, because the browser is trying to read a path that is not being served on your server.

If you serve it at `/style.css` then you can put the href value as `style.css`, otherwise you want to put the value as the path to the css file either from the root of the site if it begins with /, or relative to /hello otherwise.

The simplest way to serve it would be to add it as a second servlet on your server, with a path of `style.css`. There are better ways, but these tend to be server dependent.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thanks for your answer. Not sure how to "serve" the css file. Is this something I have to config in Gradle?

Comment: Expanded answer to cover how to serve css